# What is the benefit of using a list to represent a string?

Tags: python, string

What is the benefit of using a list to represent a string, outside of the fact that its mutable. Does it have better time complexity if used inside of a class?

Comment: A string or list has no time complexity. Operations on them have. So if you want to talk about time complexity you have to name the operation.

Comment: Using a list to represent a string? Who does that? Where did you see that?

Comment: @KlausD. that's exactly what I mean, which operations are better in which scenarios? Amongst append, copying from a string, deleting a string

Comment: @KellyBundy I saw a solution on leetcode which used a list of characters to represent the string

Comment: Where on leetcode?

Comment: "Does it have better time complexity if used inside of a class?" That doesn't make sense. Time complexity applies to *an algorithm*.  Or to a certain operation in a fat structure, not the data structure itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python, and it is therefore a common practice to convert a string into a list of single-character strings to perform multiple index-based modifications before joining the characters back into a string. Without such a conversion, one would have to resort to slicing the string and joining the fragments into a new string, with each modification costing a time complexity of *O(n)* rather than *O(1)*, which list-based modifications can do.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. Not sure why everyone else was so unhelpful and disrespectful.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it has better time complexity, its big-O performance should be the same.  But when you're indexing a string, Python needs to generate a new single-character string every time.  For a list it will just hand you a reference to the already existing single character string.

Comment: I suppose, but if your application's bottleneck is somehow the allocation of length-one strings, then you have much bigger problems.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I try not to judge why someone asks a question.  And I save my downvotes for answers that are factually incorrect.

Comment: Note, in CPython, single character strings are interned! Of course, that is an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied on, string interning in particular being an arcane aspect of the CPython runtime

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't know that about single character strings.  Is it all characters, or some specific subset?  Unicode has a lot of characters!

Comment: Maybe there is some subset, but I do think it is simply all length-1 strings. Note, this doesn't mean they are cached, and most programs would only ever generate a tiny subset of all possible length-1 unicode strings

Comment: soo `x = 'åß∂ƒ'; print(x[1] is x[1])` .... although... `[(x[i] is x[i], x[i]) for i in range(len(x))]` gives me: `[(True, 'å'), (True, 'ß'), (False, '∂'), (False, 'ƒ')]`!!! So clearly not *all*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `[i for i in range(0x110000) if chr(i) is chr(i)] == list(range(256))` is true for me on CPython 3.9.4.

Comment: (And `r = range(0x110000); s = ''.join(map(chr, r)); [i for i in r if s[i] is s[i]] == list(range(256))` as well, just to be sure.)

Comment: @KellyBundy interesting.  So it appears to be like the integers, where the small integers are cached and the rest aren't.